# error: unexpected input

Tags: r

Observe following code:

```
Xij <- scan(n=45)
6398400 6273897 6038777 5810740 5673521 5688332 5669445 5682840 5679432   
5723561 5555929 5345696 5321179 5199592 5165409 5130744 5132372     
4717909 4925673 4999103 4960733 4840036 4824080 4821902             
7115151 7114401 7039423 6967723 6967513 6901684                 
8203359 8286980 8222974 8323470 8067521                     
5930080 5862383 5994123 6017566                         
5558436 5754304 5613530                             
4595506 5074887                                 
3443322

n <- length(Xij); TT <- trunc(sqrt(2*n))
i <- rep(1:TT,TT:1); j <- sequence(TT:1)
i <- as.factor(i); j <- as.factor(j)
```

If I now try to run following command:

```
Xij.1 <- xtabs(Xij˜i+j)
```

I get the error 'Error: unexpected input in "Xij.1 <- xtabs(Xij˜"

This exercise is however, analog to an example from the book 'Modern Actuarial Risk Theory using R'.

Does somebody know what is possibly wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works fine:

`xtabs(Xij~i+j)`

Notice that in R formula you have to use tilde character `~` rather then `˜` character. Those are two different characters.